# onmousedown on dynamically generated html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, mousedown

I am using jQuery.ajax to read and render XML file into HTML.

The below code generates a table of buttons for each data record in the XML:

```
$(xml).children('run').each(function() {
    var runname = $(this).children('name').text();

    buttonHtml = '<tr><td class="expbutton" id="runExpButton" onmousedown="myFunc(runname)">Click me</td></tr>';

    $('#Runs').append(buttonHtml);
});​
```

It's not hard to see what I want to achieve here. But obviously it does not work.

My question is how do I achieve this in jQuery? If I use .live or .on methods I don't have access to the local variable such as "runname".

**[EDIT]**

Attempt on using jQuery.data():

```
$(xml).children('run').each(function() {
    var runname = $(this).children('name').text();

    buttonHtml = '<tr><td class="expbutton" id="runExpButton" onmousedown="myFunc(runname)">Click me</td></tr>';
    $('#runExpButton').data('runname', runname);
    $('#Runs').append(buttonHtml);
});​

$('#runExpButton').live('click',function() {
    alert($(this).data("runname"));
});
```

It does not seem to work? Only one of the buttons has the correct data value.

Because all the buttons have the same id, I suspect .data() doesn't work with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I believe you are looking for is jQuery [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

You can store data for an html element and then pull that data in when the element is clicked.

An example would be

```
$(xml).children('run').each(function(index) {
    var runname = $(this).children('name').text();
    buttonHtml = '<tr><td class="expbutton" id="runExpButton'+index+'">Click me</td></tr>';
    $('#Runs').append(buttonHtml);
    $('#runExpButton'+index).data('runname', runname);
});​

$(document).on('click', '.expbutton', function(){
     alert($(this).data('runname'));
});
```

I edited your code to add unique IDs to each cell you are adding to the table.

Comment: Is $(this).data("runname") in .live() correct? Can you please have a look at my attempt. It did not work.

Comment: You need to call the .data after you append the element to the table. Before you append it to the table it doesn't exist.

Comment: @user1792714 I edited my code to show you how to make unique ids for each cell. You don't want multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: Now it works. However I have to use .live. If I use .on as you did, it wouldn't work. Why? [OK my jquery version is old...]

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that you are using an old version of jQuery. To quote the docs, _As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers._

Answer (score 0):

You can change you HTML to something like

```
buttonHtml = '<tr><td class="expbutton" id="runExpButton" data-name="' + runname + '">Click me</td></tr>';
```

and then, as Blake stated correctly, use $(element).data('name')  to get that value. 
So bind the event with .live, read data-name, profit!