# jQuery mousedown not working in chrome/safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousedown

I'm using this piece of code to wrap a link around a (dynamically) created div, which works good so far in firefox, but not on safari/chrome and ie.

I already know that I should use pointer events, but I'm not sure how to achieve this, since I still need the ".on" event, because of the dynamically created div.

```
// Create a link around the ID
$(".psv-hud").on('mousedown', '#psv-marker-job1', function() {
    $(this).wrap( "<a href='/psv-marker-job1/'></a>" );
});
```

Any ideas how I could solve this?

Comment: is this element was present at the time when you executed the jQuery code `.psv-hud`
if it was not present the code won't work.

Comment: Is this code within `$(document).ready(function(){});`?

Comment: @RohitSharma Yes it is, but this was not the problem. My code is working in firefox, but not on other browser, because mousedown is no longer supported. I need a solution to bypass mousdown with a pointer event, but I dont know how...

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an element that is already there when the DOM is created. In the parameters, you specify the elements you want to add the mousedown method. By simply assigning $('.enemy'), it will attach the method to those that are already present in the DOM.

```
$('body').on('mousedown', '.enemy', function(event) {
    //attack code
}
```

[Jquery on mousedown not working on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226024/jquery-on-mousedown-not-working-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Comment: Thanks for your afford, but this was not the problem. My code is working in firefox, but not on other browser, because mousedown is no longer supported. I need a solution to bypass mousdown with a pointer event, but I dont know how...

Comment: Oh, maybe you could try using the native Web API? Just a thought. Examples: https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/events/#mouse-events

Answer (score 0):

If this code don't work, `.psv-hub` isn't exist when mousedown event bind.

First, check change `.psv-hub` -> `document`.

```
$(".psv-hud").on('mousedown', '#psv-marker-job1', function() {
    $(this).wrap( "<a href='/psv-marker-job1/'></a>" );
});
```

Show me the example page.

Comment: Thanks for your afford, but this was not the problem. My code is working in firefox, but not on other browser, because mousedown is no longer supported. I need a solution to bypass mousdown with a "pointer event", but I dont know how...